# trouble loading R packages in Netlogo

Tags: r, netlogo

I have a model that uses the R extension, which previously worked on my old pc. I have a new laptop and I'm trying to get the model to run, however, I'm getting the following error when I set-up the model (which includes loading some R packages):

```
Error during configuration of JavaGD plot device: org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error in path.package("JavaGD"): none of the packages are loaded
```

and

```
Extension exception: Error in R-Extension: Error in Eval: 
org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called 'dplyr'

error while observer running R:EVAL
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'
```

I've confirmed that the packages are indeed installed and I've double checked I have the right settings for the `r.home` and `jri.home.paths`, and the path in the environment.

I'm using Netlogo 6.2.0 and R x64 4.1.1.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I added `r.lib.paths=~/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/` to the user.properties file (note the trailing slash), but this only leads back to another error failing to load the `stats` package.

Comment: Sadly, no. I tried your suggestion about the trailing slash in user.properties but I also have the issue with failure to load stats package.

Comment: I have done some trouble shooting and now the error message is slightly different: Extension exception: Error in R-Extension: Error in Eval: 
org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error : package or namespace load failed for 'dplyr' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Yes, this looks exactly like the error I had. :/